# SSL Certificate Connection Error with VS 2015

Tags: iis, ssl, https, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

So SSL is enabled, and the first time I used it, it asked me for the certificate and worked absolutely fine! I approved it and let it be.

Now, whenever I attempt to debug in Chrome, it throws an **SSL Connection Error** and **ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR**

I've tried deleting the IIS Express certificate and re-enabling SSL in VS 2015. I've also tried repairing IIS Express, and repairing VS 2015 (which took a while) but to no avail.

I've tried changing ports for SSL and I made sure the SSL port matches the port in the project 'Web' properties as the default URL so that I am using the right port/link every time I debug. Also useless.

Why did it suddenly stop working? No clue, and I don't know how to get it working again.

Here's the rewrite rule:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Thank you guys in advance!